# How to solve $\arctan x - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3 x}= 0$

Tags: calculus

How do I solve $$\arctan x - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3 x}= 0$$
Is it possible to solve this equation analytically?
I have not found any proper way to do it yet.
I tried using WolframAlpha but they didn't provide any step-by-step solution for how they solved it.

Comment: a plot shows us that we can find two solutions (real solutions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $\alpha\in(0,1)$ there is a unique positive real solution of $\arctan x=\alpha x$ by the concavity of the arctangent function. However, the inverse function of $\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ does not have a nice analytic expression. In this case we are lucky, since it is not difficult to notice that $x=\pm\sqrt{3}$ is a root of $f(x)=\arctan x-\frac{\pi}{x\sqrt{3}}$. Moreover, $f(x)$ is an odd function, and an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, since:

$$ g(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x-\frac{\pi x}{\sqrt{3}},\quad g'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}<0,$$
so $x=\pm\sqrt{3}$ are **the only** solutions.

Comment: You'd probably want the inverse of $x\cdot\arctan x$ and not $\frac{\arctan x}x$

Comment: @KristofferRyhl: yes, that was just for explaining a common phenomenon.

Comment: Of course, the inverse function of $\frac{\arctan x}x$ just doesn't help solving this problem, or a more general case of it.